# I receive error 400 after changing from Class component to Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, youtube-api

It was working a while ago, the searchBar component was a class component and I tried to change it to a functional component but suddenly I receive error 400.  I tried to create a new youtube API but it keeps showing.

is it because of api?

Here is my App.js

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import youtube from './api/youtube'
import { SearchBar, VideoDetail, VideoList } from './components'

const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideo] = useState([])
  const [selectdvideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null)

  const onFormSubmit = async (value) => {
    const response = await youtube.get('search', {
      params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 5,
        key: '',
        q: value,
      },
    })

    console.log('hello')
    setVideo(response.data.items)
    setSelectedVideo(response.data.items[0])
  }

  return (
    <Grid justifyContent="center" container spacing={10}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Grid container spacing={10}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <SearchBar onFormSubmit={onFormSubmit} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8}>
            <VideoDetail video={selectdvideo} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <VideoList videos={videos} onSelectVideo={setSelectedVideo} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the searchBar

```
import { Paper, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const SearchBar = ({ onFormSubmit }) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)

  const onKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      onFormSubmit(searchTerm)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Paper elavtion={6} style={{ padding: '25px' }}>
      <TextField 
        fullWidth
        label="Search..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
      />
    </Paper>
  )
}

export default SearchBar
[enter image description here][1]
```

I receive this error
https://ibb.co/Vpz9nKG

Comment: Check the api. Everything is fine

Comment: Be careful to avoid posting your API keys on StackOverflow!

Comment: check the `network` tab and see what is the response from api. No issue found in  your code. Also +1 to Jotha